# How to remove white space in a multiple line HTML arrangement?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a template with a Handlebar-style templating system:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="!panoURL">
  {{ $t('invalidPanorama') }}{{ $t(objectName) | lowercase }}{{ $t('period') }}
</div>
```

Output message: `Please re-upload this panorama.`

As you can see the message is localized; it also has a Chinese version. Since in Chinese words don't have spaces I have to place the spaces in the localized string. Not in the template.

To improve redeability I did this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="!panoURL">
  {{ $t('invalidPanorama') }}
  {{ $t(objectName) | lowercase }}
  {{ $t('period') }}
</div>
```

But a space is added after each string.

How to do write the structure like the second example but produce the example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your correct, this is a classical white space issue when using inline elements, where the markup's broken lines gives that space, so try this

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="!panoURL">
     {{ $t('invalidPanorama') }}<!--
  -->{{ $t(objectName) | lowercase }}<!--
  -->{{ $t('period') }}
</div>
```